# DirectShow in asp.net needs controller handle

Tags: c#, asp.net, directshow, controllers, handlers

Im building an asp.net webcam website and I need help. (using DirectShowLib)

In order to show the webcam stream I need a controller handle to pass.

In asp.net there is no handle property for any controller.

I know I can create a windows form controller and import it to my website but that requires the clients approval and I want to avoid it.

Any ideas what can I use instead?

Comment: You know you can use DirectShow just on your local computer, right?! To stream your webcam, you need a streaming server and a video-client like VLC or Silverlight. If you have a IP-Camera you can include the MJPEG stream of this camera, most browser can playback this (except IE).

Comment: I want to be able to do this from any computer. not just my own.

Comment: What should the user see on your website, his local webcam or a webcam in the network?

Answer (score 0):

Make a class library project and add a user control form to display your webcam . then make it as a activex control and use it in your asp.net project.

Check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c.aspx) for more information.

Mark as answer if this helps..!!!

Comment: A class like that requires clients approval, which im trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh you specified that in your main question. I don't think that will be smoothly possible.